# Upload file to project specific directory dynamically in multer

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs, multer

I am trying to add a file upload feature in my MEAN.js application. I made use of multer, but it places all the files directly in the destination specified at the time of initializing multer. I want to upload files to directories specific to the program for which they are being uploaded (of course create directory dynamically if it doesn't exist). Where should I specify the custom logic of creating directories on the fly and placing files in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to this problem is to use busboy, which let's you store your images in your desired location.

```
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var fs = require('fs');

app.post('.....',fucntion(req, res, next){
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {

      req.body[fieldname] = val;
    });
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
fstream = fs.createWriteStream("path/desiredImageName");
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function() {

           file.resume();

     });
})
return req.pipe(busboy);
})
```

Comment: No no no! Multer uses busboy behind the scenes. Multer allows you to configure the file path where you want uploaded files to go!!! Example:


    var multer = require('multer');
    var path = require('path')
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, 'uploads/xml');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
      }
});

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

Comment: Jordy Cuan's answer is better

Answer (score 6):

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing helped me. 
Finally I wrote this and it works!

My solution (I am using express 4.13 and multer 1.2):

**Imports**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer');
```

**Storage variable** (see documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage))

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var newDestination = 'uploads/' + req.params.__something;
        var stat = null;
        try {
            stat = fs.statSync(newDestination);
        } catch (err) {
            fs.mkdirSync(newDestination);
        }
        if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
            throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
        }       
        cb(null, newDestination);
    }
});
```

**Initializing Multer:**

```
var upload = multer(
    { 
        dest: 'uploads/',
        limits: {
            fieldNameSize: 100,
            fileSize: 60000000
        },
        storage: storage
    }
);
```

**Using it!**

```
router.use("/upload", upload.single("obj"));
router.post('/upload', controllers.upload_file);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. However, you can move the file to other locations after the file is uploaded. That is probably your best bet. You could make your storage object a module and change the directory dynamically via init

```
var multer = require('multer'); //  middleware for handling multipart/form-data,
    // Constructor 
    module.exports = function (name) {
        try {
            // Configuring appropriate storage 
            var storage = multer.diskStorage({
                // Absolute path
                destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                    callback(null, './uploads/'+name);
                },
                // Match the field name in the request body
                filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
                }
            });
            return storage;
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("Error :\n"+ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How should I specify my api in routes for to be used in angularjs controller?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, I'm kinda confused on what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Punit oh, sorry i guess i was a little to late, looks like you got your answer.